# get date from string using nsdateformatter

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsdateformatter

I have some problem getting right date from string. My code is as follows:

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSLog(@"ex date == %@", [df dateFromString:@"2013-04-09 15:57:17"]);
```

and it prints like this `2013-04-09 10:27:17 +0000`
it should display like this and should be print like this 2013-04-09 15:57:17
Can anyone help?

Comment: There are easily 1000 prior questions here asking the exact same thing.  Find a few and study them.

Comment: what do you want it to print? what is the question?

Comment: which format you want to get??

Comment: (A little curious as to why someone deleted my comment about the OP being from India, as it was quite relevant to his issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use my method for that...

```
-(NSString *)changeDateFormat:(NSString*)stringDate dateFormat:(NSString*)dateFormat getwithFormat:(NSString *)getwithFormat{


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];

    dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:getwithFormat];

    NSString *convertedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"Converted String : %@",convertedString);
    return convertedString;
}
```

use it like bellow...

```
NSString *strSDate = [self changeDateFormat:@"2013-04-09 15:57:17" dateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" getwithFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSLog(@"ex date == %@",strSDate );
```

and it will print..

**ex date ==  09/04/2013**

see [My Blog...](http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/)